# Find the point where the line and the plane intersects

Tags: linear-algebra

The line L in $R^3$ goes through the origin. A direction vector for the line creates the angle $60^o$ against the positive x-axis and and the angle $45^o$ against the positive y-axis. L intersects with the plane $x + \sqrt{2}y-3z=6 $ in the point P. Find P.

So, I'm completely lost here. Don't know what to with the "angle-information", and can't find any good information online, so really basic hints on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The orienting vector of the line is a unit vector $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$ such that:

$ u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2=1$ ( because it is unitary)

$(u_1,u_2,u_3)\cdot(1,0,0)=\frac{1}{2}$  ( because it form an angle go $60°$ with the $x$ axis)

$(u_1,u_2,u_3)\cdot(0,1,0)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ ( because it form an angle go 45°
 with the y axis)

can you do from this?

Comment: I'll give it a go, just 1 question, is it a particular reason that the direction vector is unitary?

Comment: No. It can be not unitary, but I prefer .... so all components are fixed and, more important, the dot product  with other unitary vectors is simply the $\cos$ of the angle between them.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The direction unitary vectors $\vec v$ for the line can be found by

- $\vec v \cdot \vec i= v_x \cos 60°=\frac12 v_x$
- $\vec v \cdot \vec j= v_y\cos 45°=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}v_y$

then find the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the angles the line makes with the $x$ and $y$ axes, the unit vector of the direction of the line $L$ is $$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ k\end{matrix}\right)$$

Since this is a unit vector, we can square and add these components and get a total of $1$, which gives two possible values for $k$, namely $\pm \frac 12$

So the equation of the line $L$ is $$\underline{r}=\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 12\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \pm\frac 12\end{matrix}\right)$$

Solving his simultaneously with the plane gives two possible values of $\lambda$ i.e. $3$ or $5$ and therefore two possible points of intersection

Comment: One of these systems has no solution, as far as I can tell.